# Is there a way to do a nested for loop to get all correlations in R?

Tags: r, loops, statistics, nested-loops, correlation

I trying to find a way to do a nested for loop in r to get every possible correlation combination of this:

`cor(y, column1 * column2)`, 
`cor(y, column1 * column3)`,
`cor(y, column1 * column4)`,
`cor(y, column2 * column3)`

or in my example:

`cor(MP, FG_pct * FGA)`, 
`cor(MP, FG_pct * FT)`,
`cor(MP, FG_pct * FT_pct)`
and so on

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for(i in 1:length(dataframe))
{
for(j in 1:length(dataframe))
{
joint_correlation(i,j)=cor(MP, dataframe(i) * dataframe(j));
}
}
```

My dataframe has 115 columns like shown with a small sample:

```
FG_pct FGA FT FT_pct FTA GP GS GmSc  MP    ORB

0.625   8   0  0.00   0  1  0   6.6  28.4   2   
0.500   4   0  0.00   1  2  0   2.1  17.5   0   
0.000   1   0  0.00   0  3  0   1.2  6.6    1   
0.500   6   0  0.00   0  4  0   3.6  13.7   1   
0.500   2   0  0.00   0  5  0   0.9  7.4    1
```

I want to find the correlation for `cor(MP, column1 * column2)` for every possible combination switched out for column1 and column2. This way, I wouldn't have to do every single one of them separately. I believe a loop going through all of the scenarios is the best way. If possible, I would like to save the output for each correlation combination `cor(MP, FG_pct * FGA)`, `cor(MP, FG_pct * FT_pct)`, `cor(MP, GmSc * ORB)`, etc. in a separate column.

**EDIT**

`sessionInfo()`

```
    R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
    Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
    Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

    Matrix products: default
    BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

    Random number generation:
    RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
    Normal:  Inversion 
    Sample:  Rounding 

    locale:
    [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] dplyr_0.8.5        magrittr_1.5       ggplot2_3.3.0      corrr_0.4.2        RColorBrewer_1.1-2
    [6] readr_1.3.1        corrplot_0.84     

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

[1] Rcpp_1.0.4       rstudioapi_0.11  knitr_1.24       MASS_7.3-51.5    hms_0.5.3        tidyselect_1.0.0
[7] munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-1 R6_2.4.1         rlang_0.4.5      tools_3.6.1      grid_3.6.1      
[13] gtable_0.3.0     xfun_0.9         withr_2.1.2      assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_2.1.3     lifecycle_0.2.0 
[19] crayon_1.3.4     farver_2.0.3     purrr_0.3.3      vctrs_0.2.4      glue_1.3.2       compiler_3.6.1  
[25] pillar_1.4.3     scales_1.1.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3'
```

Comment: 115 columns or 115 rows with 10 columns? There are 6,555 combinations of 115 columns taken 2 at a time. Do you really want that many correlations? Give `cor()` a matrix and it will give you the correlation of each column with each other column. No need for any loops. Try `cor(cbind(rnorm(15), rnorm(15), rnorm(15), rnorm(15)))`.

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't want to include MP itself in the correlation; you don't want e.g. `cor(MP, MP * ORB)` . Right?  And you want each `cor` as a separate column _in a new table_, because each _cor_ is a single-value, and your starting data's columns have lengths = 5.

Comment: I have 115 columns and 171,572 rows. I do not want to include MP e.g. cor(MP, MP * ORB) so correct David. As long as I can get a final table with all of the correlation combinations (corresponding to the cor(MP, column1 * column2) formula), then I do not care how they are stored. I would like a final table with all correlation combinations if possible where I can order them from strongest to weakest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the correlations of every column multiplied by combinations of two of the remaining columns.

We can find the names of according combinations using `combn(names(dat), 2)` which we put into an `lapply`.

```
combs <- do.call(cbind.data.frame,
                 lapply("MP", rbind, combn(names(dat)[names(dat) != "MP"], 2)))
combs
#        1      2   3
# 1     MP     MP  MP
# 2 FG_pct FG_pct FGA
# 3    FGA     FT  FT
```

In another `lapply` we subset the data on the name-combinations and calculate `cor` with formula cor(*x1 ~ x2 * x3*). Simultaneously we store the names `paste`d as formula in an `attr`ibute, to remember later what we've calculated in each iteration.

```
res.l <- lapply(combs, function(x) {
  `attr<-`(cor(dat[,x[1]], dat[,x[2]]*dat[,x[3]]),
           "what", {
             paste0(x[1], ", ", paste(x[2], "*", x[3]))})
})
```

Finally we `unlist` and `setNames` according to the attributes.

```
res <- setNames(unlist(res.l), sapply(res.l, attr, "what"))
```

#### Result

```
# MP, FG_pct * FGA  MP, FG_pct * FT     MP, FGA * FT 
#        0.2121374        0.2829003        0.4737892
```

*Check:*

(Note, that you can directly put the names, e.g. `MP, FG_pct * FGA` into the `cor` function.)

```
with(dat, cor(MP, FG_pct * FGA))
# [1] 0.2121374
with(dat, cor(MP, FG_pct * FT))
# [1] 0.2829003
with(dat, cor(MP, FGA * FT))
# [1] 0.4737892
```

To sort, use e.g. `sort(res)` or `rev(sort(res))`.

---

*Toy data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- as.data.frame(`colnames<-`(MASS::mvrnorm(n=1e4, 
                          mu=c(0.425, 4.2, 0.2, 3), 
                          Sigma=matrix(c(1, .3, .7, 0,
                                         .3, 1, .5, 0,
                                         .7, .5, 1, 0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=4), 
                          empirical=T), c("FG_pct", "MP", "FGA", "FT")))
```

Comment: This is sort of what I am looking work so great work. I have 2 questions to fix this though. For ```cor(x1 ~ x2 * x3)```, I just want x1 to be MP for all combinations. I **do not** need every column multiplied by combinations of two of the remaining columns. I just need MP multiplied by combinations of two of the remaining columns so ```cor(MP ~ x2 * x3)```. How could this be fixed? The next question is: Why do I need the error ```Error: Can't subset with `[` using an object of class factor.``` when I get to the ```res.l <- lapply...``` part? I replaced dat with my dataset.

Comment: How do I get ride of the `Error: Can't subset with `[` using an object of class factor.` when running the `res.l <- lapply` part? I have my dataset inputted to replace dat in your example. My dataset has 115 columns and 171572 rows. How do I use get `cor(MP ~ x2 * x3)` as MP multiplied by combinations of every two of the remaining columns combination?

Comment: @NikhilMorar We can fix the first issue by adapting the `combn` at the beginning a little, `rbind` `"MP"` with everything non-`"MP"`, see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for correctly the issue. Your edited answer is exactly what I have been looking for! When I put in my dataset I get an error when running the `res.l <- lapply(combs, function(x)` chunk of code. The error is: `Error: Can't subset with [ using an object of class factor.`. My combs is 3 obs. of 6441 variables. My dataset is 171572 obs. of 115 variables. Why is the error being cause when I replace my dataset into the code?

Comment: @NikhilMorar _Second issue:_ There are probably some factor/categorical variables in your `x1, x2, x3`. Could you provide `str(yourDat[c("FG_pct", "MP", "FGA", "FT", ...))])`, where `c("FG_pct", "MP", "FGA", "FT")` would be all the variables you need for this `cor` calculation?

Comment: Or `table(sapply(dat[c("FG_pct", "MP", "FGA", "FT", ...)], class))`.

Comment: I have 114 different variables that are getting passing through as you have shown in your example of 3 variables (not including MP). All of the variables are numeric as I have done `table(sapply(mydataset, class))` and `numeric 115` is my output. Should I supply you will all 115 variables (column names)?

Comment: Hmm, could you provide `sessionInfo()` as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61831434/edit)?

Comment: I have provided the `sessionInfo()`. Let me know if I can provide anything else or format it better.

Comment: Thanks. Strange, I've tried to load all your packages but can't replicate the issue. However your R version `3.6.1` is quite outdated. I'm using `4.0.0`. Could you try to update: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Comment: I also tried to put `factor`s and `NA` into the toy data, but I don't receive this error. Maybe try compare `str(dat)` and `str(yourDat)`, if there's any principal difference?

Comment: I updated to `4.0.0`, and it started working perfectly fine. The output is now displaying. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Great! Very welcome @NikhilMorar, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Store all of the combinations in a matrix:

```
x <- t(combn(115, 2))
```

Each row has two column numbers (create a matrix with your computations first to make things simpler). The you can use a loop or `sapply`. Here's a small example:

```
set.seed(42)
dta <- cor(cbind(A=rnorm(15), B=rnorm(15), C=rnorm(15), D=rnorm(15)))
x <- t(combn(4, 2))
cors <- sapply(1:6, function(i) cor(dta[, x[i, ]])[1,2])
cor.lbl <- sapply(1:6, function(i) paste(colnames(dta)[x[i, ]], collapse="-"))
names(cors) <- cor.lbl
cors
#         A-B         A-C         A-D         B-C         B-D         C-D 
#  0.08735187 -0.77672266  0.10113427 -0.60521291 -0.45853048 -0.11072996
```

Comment: I changed the 115 in ```x <- t(combn(115, 2))``` to my matrix dataframe name of 115 columns so now it is ```x <- t(combn(datamatrix, 2))```. I get: Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA). Was this the right step to take? How do I create a matrix with my computations first to make things simpler?

Comment: No, not the data, just the number of columns: `x <- t(combn(115, 2))`

Comment: Where do I add my dataset into this code to get the correlation combinations of ```cor(MP, column1 * column2)```?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer "(create a matrix with your computations first to make things simpler)", you should create a new data frame with any computed columns. That new computed data set should be used in the place of `dta` in my answer.